# Why $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\times \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ are the same + $L^1(\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2)$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Why $\mathbb R^2/ \mathbb Z^2$ is the Torus ? The Torus is indeed $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\times \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. But why $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ also gives the torus ? For me if we glue all points of $\mathbb Z^2$ together, then $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ should look as a sphere and not as a Torus ? Also, for me $L^1(\mathbb S^2)$ is the set of integrable periodic functions on $\mathbb R^2$. But in my course they wrote it as $L^1(\mathbb T^2)$ (the torus in $\mathbb R^3$). For me $L^1(\mathbb T^2)$ is the set of function $f$ s.t. $x\mapsto f(x,y )$ is $T_1$ periodic and $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $T_2$ periodic, but there is no reason to have $f$ periodic.

Comment: Think of the function $p:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ defined by $$p(x,y)=(x+\Bbb{Z},y+\Bbb{Z}).$$ You should convince yourself of the fact that $p(x_1,y_1)=p(x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ belong to the same coset of $\Bbb{Z}^2$. In other words, by the first isomorphism theorem, we have an isomorphism of groups
$$\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2\simeq \Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}.$$ Because this bijection is so natural, it is bound to be a homeomorphism also.

Comment: Also, if for $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ and all $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}$ you have $f(x,y)=f(x+n,y)$ as well as $f(x,y)=f(x,y+m)$, then surely you also have $f(x,y)=f(x+n,y+m)$. Doubly periodic.

Comment: A topological connection between the sphere and the plane comes from the stereographic projection (when you need to add a point at infinity not to miss the North pole). But, observe that in that projection there are no identifications between the points of the plane.

Comment: Or, if you start with a rectangle, you get the torus by identifying (=glueing) the pairs of points on opposite sides. You get the sphere only by identifying all the points of the border to form a single point on the sphere.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for your answer. So $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ can't be the sphere... strange, because gluing all points of $\mathbb Z^2$ look like a sphere. So for periodic function, is really $L^1(\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2)$ and not $L^1(\mathbb S^2)$ ? Or both work ?

Comment: What is your definition of a periodic function? Yet another way to think about it would be to use longitude/latitude coordinates to identify a point on the sphere. Because all the longitudes meet at the poles, for a function $f$ to be well-defined at the poles we need $f(\phi,\theta=0)$ and $f(\phi,\theta=\pi)$ to be constants. But $f$ can be periodic in both $\phi$ and $\theta$ without being a constant for selected values of $\theta$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: There is $T>0$ s.t. $f(x+T,y+T)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: That definition doesn't give you functions on either a torus or a sphere. You then get functions on $\Bbb{R}^2/M$, where $M$ is the subgroup generated by the vector $(T,T)$. Topologically that is a cylinder.

Comment: Functions on a torus correspond to $f(x+T_1,y)=f(x,y)=f(x,y+T_2)$ for some constants $T_1,T_2\neq0$. Sorry, I gotta go now. With more time I could draw pictures.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you very much for your help :) When you'll have time, I'll appreciate a draw, thank you :)